# Getting Permission denied when querying Firebase Realtime DB with orderByChild?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "items": {
            ".read": "auth.uid != null && query.orderByChild == 'owner' && query.equalTo == auth.uid"   
        }
}
```

My query function:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("items").orderByChild("owner").equalTo(firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid).ref 

ref.on('value', (v)=>{
   console.log("ok: ", v.val())
}, (e)=>{
   console.log("not allowed: ", e)
})
```

I keep getting "Permission denied". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. In my query, I called "....equalTo(...).ref"

Removing the .ref works:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("items").orderByChild("owner").equalTo(firebase.auth().currentUser?.uid)

ref.on('value', (v)=>{
   console.log("ok: ", v.val())
}, (e)=>{
   console.log("not allowed: ", e)
})
```